# powershell input array string

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, azure-runbook

I need PowerShell input in azure automation runbook in `['member1','member2','member3']` this format.
how can I convert my input to this format in Powershell, I have to pass multiple members as input.

Comment: Is this a json array, or is the similarity merely coincidence?

Comment: Since you mentioned `how can I convert my input to this format`, may I know your original input ?

Comment: @HuryShen i have to pass multiple members,lets say member1,member2,member3 (multiple values separated by comma )

Comment: Do you mean convert string `"member1, member2, member3"` to array `['member1','member2','member3']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is what I mentioned in comments, you just need to use `Split()` in powershell.

For example, your input is `$param = "member1,member2,member3"`. Then use `$result = $param.Split(",")`, the input will be convert to array in format `['member1','member2','member3']`